# cannot execute executable files x.run

Tags: software-installation, executable, install-from-source

I use Kubuntu 14 on HP Envy. I'm trying to install software  (software: MPLAB® X IDE v2.05 and MPLAB® XC32 Compiler v1.31) from .run files

this fails.

The .run files have executable flags set:

```
-rwxr-xr-x
MPLABX.run*
```

I tried:

```
./MPLABX.run*
sudo ./MPLABX.run*
sudo -i ... ./MPLABX.run*
```

Every time the same result: nothing, the terminal just shows the folder name.

I also wanted to install Skype by using the Dynamic version. In skypes README is Written:"a path for Skype to exist in.  We recommend copying the
skype binary to /usr/bin and installing sounds/, lang/ and avatars/ into
the /usr/share/skype directory."[Skype README]

I did that tried to open in Konsole the answer was:

```
bash: /usr/bin/skype: No such file or directory
```

but thats not true the file exists and is executable.
I tried also `sudo`.

What can I do do?

I have to register thos progs which should be executable?

Thanks for answers!!

Answer (score 0):

To run the program, try typing:

```
sudo sh MPLABX.run
```

the difference between `./` and `sh` is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22910/what-is-the-difference-between-and-sh-to-run-a-script).