# Weird output by declare and array

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to output the values of array element but I am getting weird output. Please have a look at it and help me solve it. Thank you.

```
n=2
declare -a myarray[$n]
myarray[0]=hey
myarray[1]=hello
myarray[2]=bye
for i in ${myarray[@]}
do
        echo $i
done
```

Output:

```
robin@robin-VirtualBox:~/lx$ sh array.sh
array.sh: 2: array.sh: declare: not found
array.sh: 3: array.sh: myarray[0]=hey: not found
array.sh: 4: array.sh: myarray[1]=hello: not found
array.sh: 5: array.sh: myarray[2]=bye: not found
array.sh: 6: array.sh: Bad substitution
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`declare` is a **bash** shell builtin, and is not  defined in the **sh** shell.

So, you must to run your script using the following command:

```
bash array.sh
```

Or add, the following [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line at the start of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Be sure that your script is exectutable:

```
 chmod +x array.sh
```

And run it using the following command:

```
./array.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script is correct, but type:

```
./array.sh
```

instead of `sh array.sh`

The difference between `./` and `sh` is explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22910/what-is-the-difference-between-and-sh-to-run-a-script).

Comment: i'm getting `permision denied`. I even tried with sudo.

Comment: Its ok, I had to make it executable. Thank you.