# unable to run ls -a in shell script file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc

This is my demo.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(ls -A) ]]; then
echo "there are files"
else
echo "no files found"
fi
```

but when i run this i get output as

```
    demo.sh: 3: demo.sh: [[: not found
    no files found
```

but there is some file on this directory

Comment: `[[` like shopt is a bash feature, so you should use a shebang in your script or run it with bash

Comment: 'shebang' == a first line in the script with the content `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @muru    even by adding #!/bin/bash .. m getting same error

Comment: @GauravSingh how are you running the script?

Comment: @muru sh demo.sh

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/22910/what-is-the-difference-between-and-sh-to-run-a-script about that you should run with `bash demo.sh ` or `./demo.sh`

Comment: @muru . Nice :)