# Do I always need to make a file executable to run it?

Tags: bash, files, executable

I mean if I just use `bash` to run the file like `bash ./myscript.sh` will it be enough or there are some pitfalls?

Comment: If you call it like that, you don't need to make it executable.

Comment: @StefanHamcke so there is no difference between making it executable and run by `./myscript.sh` or run it explicitly by calling `bash ./myscript.sh`, right?

Comment: This depends on the shebang.

Comment: @RoVo the shebang is `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: And what does `type bash` say. If it's the same, there will be no difference. Or if you run `/bin/bash myscript.sh`.

Comment: If that's your shebang, then your current shell will always start a subshell `bash` which executes the commands in your script, provided the command `bash` in your shell starts `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @RoVo it says the same. Thanks RoVo and Stefan Hamcke!

Comment: or maybe better [What is the difference between ./ and sh to run a script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22910/what-is-the-difference-between-and-sh-to-run-a-script).